# Execute files on local windows website client

Tags: javascript, html, windows, google-chrome

I want to write a program which, when installed, serves as a "daemon" for websites which specifically can interact with that program. I'm searching for some kind of good practise. What I've found already found is `window.open('file:///S:Test/Test.bat')` and `ActiveXObject` but both of those seem not really secure or trust worthy(bad practise).

Comment: It's called a *DAEMON*

Comment: Without setting up your own MIME type, opening any local application from the browser is a terrible practice.

Comment: Custom URI Scheme?

Comment: just init a download of a specific MIME, and associate the type with your executable.